# Move files, check for duplicates and rename incrementally if present

Tags: powershell

I have a script that looks at the source folder and then the destination folder and decides if the sub-folders are present.  If not, it creates the corresponding folder.  Once that is done, it moves all of the files in the sub folders to the destination.  Problem - There are duplicate files that need can't be overwritten.  I need a way to check for duplicates and if found, increment the source file name by -1.  There may be incremented files already.

My current script works flawlessly to create needed sub-folders and move files but I loose any previous files.

```
$SFolder = "C:\Temp\Test\Source\"
$DFolder = "C:\Temp\Test\Destination\"

$folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $SFolder -Directory 
foreach ($folder in $folders) {

  Get-ChildItem -File "$sfolder\$folder" |
  Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.LastWriteTime -lt [datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(-5)} | 
  Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime | 
  Group-Object -Property {$_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy")} |
  ForEach-Object {
    if (!(Test-Path -Path "$dfolder\$folder" -PathType Container -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
      New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$dfolder\$folder"
    }
    $_.group|move-item -Destination "$dfolder\$folder" -PassThru
  }
}
```

The script as written works great.  Here is what I need. I start with the following:

```
Source        test1\05013018-22503-652469-1  (no file extension)
              test1\05013018-22503-652469-2

Destination   test2\05013018-22503-652469-1
              test2\05013018-22503-652469-1-1
              test2\05013018-22503-652469-1-2
```

I want the following result after running the script:

```
Source        test1\

Destination   test2\05013018-22503-652469-1
              test2\05013018-22503-652469-1-1
              test2\05013018-22503-652469-1-2
              test2\05013018-22503-652469-1-3
              test1\05013018-22503-652469-2
```

Comment: Your source already has a trailing `-1` How to determine if this should be incremented or another `-1` appended?

Comment: Each file could have -1 through -30 as each file corresponds to a specific board.  If there already is a -1, then the file needs to be -1-1 or -18-1 or 27-1.